# I'm confused by the right click menu in IntellijIdea in Git tab

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, menu, rebase

I should notice that I'm new to programming. I'm confused by the right-click menu in Android Studio and Idea in the "Git" tab. I will use the following terms:
<current_branch> - the branch we previously switched to with checkout.
<selected_branch> - The branch we right clicked on.
When we right-click on a branch, the menu contains, among other things, the following options:

- Rebase <current_branch> **onto <origin/selected_branch>**
- Merge <origin/selected_branch> **into <current_branch>**

---

- Pull **into <current_branch>** using Rebase
- Pull **into <current_branch>** using Merge

---

[Right click menu in Idea in the "Git" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTLNB.jpg)
I'm confused by the grouping of these options in the menu. It turns out that in the 1st option (Rebase) we make changes in one branch (selected_branch), and in the next three we make changes in another branch (current_branch). In my opinion, it would be logical:

1. Either in the first two options do rebase/merge to one branch (origin/selected_branch), and in the next two options (pull into...) to another (current_branch).
2. Or in all 4 options do pull/merge/rebase into the same branch (current_branch)
3. Or group menu options differently, so it doesn't look like rebase and merge (upper two options) are going to the same branch.
   Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. In this case, please correct me.

I used the mentioned commands to pull the changes from the remote branch to the local branch. I want to figure out from which branch to which branch changes are made in each of the menu options mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #2 is correct: All 4 options will only affect your currently checked out branch (`current_branch`). The wording of "rebase onto" is a little confusing at first, because it sounds like you're adding commits to that branch and modifying it, but instead, the wording:

> **rebase branch X onto branch Y** means:
>
> Take all of the (non-merge) commits on branch `X` that are not reachable by branch `Y`, and replay them, one by one, in order, on-top of branch `Y`, and then reset branch `X` to point to the end result.

Note in the above paragraph the word "reachable" is used because Git history is a graph. It's basically a way of saying whether or not one commit is in the history of another commit (or branch).

As for the difference between the two groups: rebase and merge, vs pulling with rebase or merge, the only difference is that with pull you will also perform a `git fetch`, meaning the origin branches will be updated if they have changed on the remote server since the last time you fetched (or pulled). If you use just rebase or merge, the commands will be performed with whatever commit `origin/selected_branch` is pointing to at that moment. Typically your remote is on another server, so you must be online in order to pull and get the latest. Rebase and Merge without pulling can be done even when you are offline.

**Side Note:** you probably don't want to rebase a shared branch, such as `master`, which in your screenshot is the top most (underlined) option  when you have a feature branch checked out. The only time that top option might make sense is if you have a shared branch like `master` currently checked out, and then you right click on a feature branch with the intent to rebase it onto `master`.

**Disclaimer:** I've never used Android Studio, however, I know what these options mean in other tools, and I think it's safe to assume they have the same meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

Terminology can be confusing at start, especially understanding the usage of rebase and merge.
Regarding this specific topic, I suggest you try: https://learngitbranching.js.org/, to learn git branching in more detail.

In Layman's terms: Both rebase and merge update project’s source code. However, the difference is how commit history is handled.

As for these 4 options you have mentioned, all 4 update your current branch as TTT already mentioned except that with pull GIT fetch is performed and you receive the latest version of your remote branch (in this case master)

To be exact:

**Pull into Current Using Rebase** (for remote branches) to fetch changes from the selected branch and rebase the current branch on top of these changes.

**Checkout and Rebase onto Current** (for both remote and local branches) to check out the selected branch and rebase it on top of the branch that is currently checked out. If the remote branch doesn't exist locally, IntelliJ IDEA will silently create a tracked local branch, checkout into it and rebase.

**Rebase Current onto Selected** (for both remote and local branches) to rebase the branch that is currently checked out on top of the selected.

All of these 4 options are git commands with pull being a coupled git command (fetch + merge/rebase) and once you execute them both can be seen in the console.

[image: An example of Pull into using Merge]

**VS**

[image: Merge into]

You can find more information here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#rebase-branch-onto-another-branch

And you can try out: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8554-ide-features-trainer (git part is interesting)